Is the Lovasz Number of a graph defined for infinite graphs?
I am naively trying to use the Lovasz number for a problem with an infinite graph. Wikipedia says:

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph on $n$ vertices. An ordered set of $n$ unit vectors $U = (u_i \mid i \in V) \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is called an orthonormal representation of $G$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ if $u_i$ and $u_j$ are orthogonal whenever vertices $i$ and $j$ are not adjacent in $G$.
The Lovasz number $\vartheta$ of a graph $G$ is defined as follows:
$\vartheta(G) = \min \limits_{c,U} \max \limits_{i \in V} \frac{1}{(c^T u_i)^2},$
where $c$ is a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $U$ is an orthonormal representation of $G$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

I'm no graph theory expert, but I know that sometimes things that work for finite graphs don't work for infinite ones. Does anyone know if this definition still makes sense if the graph is infinite?
